# UITableViewCells disappearing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

All UITableCells disappear on scroll and touch in the UITableView.
Everything is done programmatically and I use the standard UITableViewCell class.

I read somewhere that the array containing my cell data may be emptied and the view can therefore not load the data on scroll. However, I don't know how to verify this.

Here is my TableView delegate and DataSource:

```
class LessonTable: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    private var lessons = [LessonItem]()
    public var backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.97, alpha: 1)

    func addLessons(_ lessons: [LessonItem], tableView: UITableView){ 
        tableView.beginUpdates()

        //Construct array of indexPaths
        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        for i in 0...lessons.count {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: lessons.count - 1 + i, section: 0))
        }

        //Append all lessons to Lessons array
        self.lessons.append(contentsOf: lessons)

        //Insert rows
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)

        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return lessons.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lessonCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = backgroundColor

        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = lessons[row].Title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = lessons[row].Start.Formatted() + " - " + lessons[row].Stop.Formatted()

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        let row = indexPath.row
        print(lessons[row].Title)
    }
}
```

In my ViewController's ViewDidLoad method I'm doing the following:

```
let upcomingLessonsTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: (card.frame.size.width), height: 90))
    let upcomingLessonsTableViewData = LessonTable()
    upcomingLessonsTableView.dataSource = upcomingLessonsTableViewData
    upcomingLessonsTableView.delegate = upcomingLessonsTableViewData
    upcomingLessonsTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "lessonCell")
    upcomingLessonsTableView.backgroundColor = upcomingLessonsTableViewData.BackgroundColor
    card.addSubview(upcomingLessonsTableView)
```

And also

```
upcomingLessonsTableViewData.addLessons(upcomingEvents, tableView: upcomingLessonsTableView)
```

where `upcomingEvents` is an array.

NEW DISCOVERY.
When setting a timer that continuously prints out the contents of my lessons array, the cells doesn't disappear. Why? No clue.

Comment: When are you calling AddLessons?

Comment: I'm doing that in my ViewController's ViewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make below variable as global.
let upcomingLessonsTableViewData;

Comment: Scope of the variable. share more code so i can explain in better.

Comment: I understand that the scope is changed, but what does that have to do with the UITableView? If it's not because the local variable inside ViewDidLoad is removed when the function has completed running?

Comment: As per code local variable will be released and app should crash. Could share your swift file for more information. i cant say anything with those lines code.

Comment: I suppose, if you continuously scrolling all records will be disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRow` method add this `as! LessonCell` your `let cell` line
Should be like:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lessonCell", for: indexPath) as! LessonCell
```

Comment: LessonCell class doesn't exist. I'm using the standard UITableViewCell, therefore the extra cast would make no difference. Right?

Comment: Do you have a xib file for the cell? And a class for that xib? or not? @AxelBoberg

Comment: I don't have a xib. However I just made a class for the cells since I had to make a few adjustments, named LessonCell as in your code.

Comment: See the solution above. I had to make the TableViewData-variable, the instance of the Data/Delegate class, global. Thank you for your help!